# Is energy ultimately the ONLY thing in the universe

Tags: energy

Is it a true statement that everything is made up of ONLY energy?

If that is true is it therefore also true that there is only ONE thing in the universe ... ENERGY?

Comment: Questions like this are more difficult to answer than you might imagine at first. What do you mean by "made up of only energy?"  It may seem silly, because most of us have an intuitive sense of what energy is, but as you push towards the extremes precision in that terminology starts to matter. Generally speaking, most scientific models do not agree with the statement you make, because the universe consists of things they would not call energy. However, if you are very particular with your definitions,you can get into cases where your definition is so wide that "energy" encompasses everything

Answer (score 1):

I think it is overly simplistic to say that everything is "made of" only energy; energy is a broader concept than just describing what things are made out of. There are other things that have to be considered, like fields, which can carry energy from place to place, but aren't really made of energy themselves; they are separate entities. So pretty much everything can be understood in terms of energy, but energy is not all there is.

From a cosmological standpoint, the universe pretty much has matter, radiation, and a cosmological constant. Matter is... *kind of* energy, but more accurately it is equivalent to energy localized in space to some degree, as in Einstein's mass-energy equivalence $E=mc^2$ (so it is called mass-energy). Radiation isn't made of energy, although it carries energy from place to place; it consists as an oscillation in the electromagnetic field. The cosmological constant (vacuum energy) has a constant energy *density*... but isn't just energy sitting around. Again, it is something else. Long story short, you need way more than just energy to understand everything that is.

Comment: Things are not made of energy. In either a broader or narrower definition. Things are also not made out of mass, momentum, temperature, length etc.

Answer (score 1):

Things aren't made of energy, temperature or velocity. Things are made of quantum fields (electron field, photon field, etc.), and the fields can have energy, "velocity" (momentum), temperature, etc.

Comment: I thank you for your thoughts and comments.

Perhaps it would help if I asked if any of the things mentioned so far could exist if there were no energy ... or are they merely relative to, measurements of, ways of transporting or describing or otherwise adjuncts to energy.

Comment: If with "if there were no energy" you mean "energy=0 everywhere", then, the only thing that can exist is scalar vaccum espectation values, like the higgs field zero mode (something like a filled river, with no waves or any kind of water movement).

Comment: If you mean "if energy doesn't make sense", because energy exist because the physical laws at every time are the same (something called Noether theorem for the woman mathematician that discovered it, the most important theorem for physics on all the twenty century), then there can be things, but it will be a REALLY STRANGE universe (because the physical laws today won't be related at all with the physical laws of tomorrow).